# Magento Frontend Redirects to example.com/setup/index.php/session/unlogin

Tags: magento2.3

I have installed Magento 2.3 latest version with sample data and redirects to

example.com/setup/index.php/session/unlogin

when I open frontend.

Comment: in which OS did you install it?

Comment: I have installed on Linux

Comment: found this before (but it's not recommended just a temporary fix) changing in php.ini this one cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 to  `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`

Comment: @magefms Please post your solution

Comment: did it solve the issue? oaky I'll post it

Comment: It's not working

Comment: did you restart apache after edit?

Comment: Yes already did it

Answer (score 1):

Modify your **`php.ini`**
by changing

**`cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`**

to

**`cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`**

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue. Problem was with browser cache. It was not working in Chrome but working fine in the firefox.

Just flushed cache and now it's working in all browsers.